# Samsung Galaxy S3 latest update

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-3, android-versions

I want to update my Samsung Galaxy S3 to latest android release. I think the official latest release is 4.4.

But I want to go beyond 4.4, but how ?

Comment: Flash a custom ROM this will bring a higher version to your device

Comment: You cannot expect official updates for an old device that too from Samsung. If you need to update and flash a custom ROM, you would have to [root](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=root+samsung+galaxy+s3&oq=root+samsung+galaxy+s3&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.16877j0j4&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)  your device and flash a [custom ROM](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rom+galaxy+s3&oq=ROM+galaxy&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l3.7888j0j4&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#q=Xda+rom+galaxy+s3&tbs=qdr:m) meant specifically for your device variant

Comment: @beeshyams Can you please provide me some links to 'flash a custom ROM'. Is it a piece of hardware or ...?

Comment: Custom ROM is your phone software prepared by developers as opposed to Stock ROM, which came shipped with it. I have linked above (click on custom ROM on above comment) and research the possibilities. Not to put you off, you would need to invest a lot of time in reading and understanding and it can't be addressed here in one question. If there is something you don't understand, you can surely ask that here. Best site is XDA. Search for your device ROMs there